# Including both input and outcome variables in SPSS Modeler model

Tags: spss-modeler

I am a new SPSS Modeler user.  I have tried to build a simple decision-tree model for predicting safe births using only a couple of input variables.  In the decision tree that gets produced, and the resulting table, only the binary outcome variable seems to have been read, saved, and run.  I have tried re-marking the input variables and the binary (flag) outcome variable, causing them to be read, then saved, then the whole model re-run.  But the model does not seem to change.  Hoping someone can point me to what I am overlooking.

Comment: Are you using the scripting language? It might help to include some code or diagrams help demonstrate the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the note.  I appreciate it.  Something is screwy.  I am going to work on it for awhile with customer service.